# What ways are there to automate iOS devices list within the Provisioning Portal?

Tags: ios, provisioning, ad-hoc-distribution

I'm after some a script or tool to automatically add iPhone, iPad, etc devices to the Provisioning Portal. Is there anything out there (preferably OSS) that I can use?

Bonus points for generating Ad-Hoc certificates!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one called **MoProPro**. It also generates mobile provisioning files.

http://github.com/tupil/MoProPro